# Can't fill my drawing with the Bucket tool in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-cs4

I drew an image, scanned it, opened it in Illustrator, did **Live Trace**, and then proceeded to use the Pen tool. Now when I try to put colors on my nicely drawn image using the Bucket tool I get this error:

> Cannot convert to a Live Paint group because the selection contains Tracing objects plus other types of art. Please convert Tracing objects separately.

I went on Google and found out a suggestion to do so:

- Object > Live Paint > Make

However, that's not working and it's giving me another error:

> The selection contains objects that cannot be converted, Live Paint groups can only contain paths and compound paths. Clipping paths are not allowed.

So, how can I use the Bucket tool to fill my drawing?

Comment: Can you post or link to an image that gives similar results? There are two potential routes-- a) adjust Live Trace options so you don't get clipping paths, or b) use the Pathfinder panel to use the clipping path(s) to trim the art. Once you don't have clipping paths you should be able to use Live Paint. FWIW Illustrator CS6 has a different vectorizing solution so you could give that a shot. A free 30-day demo is available.